# OSX "clang++ -lboost_mpi"` ->"ld: library not found for -lboost_mpi" after brew install boost --with-mpi

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew, boost-mpi

After installing boost with mpi support using brew I still get the error `ld: "library not found for -lboost_mpi"` when I run `clang++ -lboost_mpi`. What can I do to overcome this? I installed boost using brew:

```
$ brew install boost --with-mpi --without-single
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-1.58.0.tar.bz2
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib --without-icu --without-libraries=python
==> ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib -d2 -j4 --layout=tagged --user-config=user-config.jam install t
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0: 10668 files, 300M, built in 10.9 minutes
```

How can I use `clang++ -lboost_mpi` successfully?

```
$ mdfind -name libboost_mpi
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib/libboost_mpi-mt.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib/libboost_mpi-mt.a

$ clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib -lboost_mpi
ld: library not found for -lboost_mpi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour when you're building boost with brew on OSX is a tagged build - if you looked a the build output you would have seen something like:

```
./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib -d2 -j8 --layout=tagged --user-config=user-config.jam install threading=multi link=shared,static
```

and the `--layout=tagged` causes multi-threaded versions to be post-fixed with `-mt`.

This means your boost_mpi library is called: `boost_mpi-mt`, and that's what you should link to, so the library you're linking to is `libboost_mpi-mt`, so the option is `-lboost_mpi-mt`.

You could also have looked in the `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib` directory for the library - it would have hinted at this as well.

> If you want to get an untagged build (i.e. without the -mt) then *edit* the boost recipe (using `brew edit boost`) and replace the `--layout=tagged` with `--layout=system`. This may cause other things to break, though.

Comment: In addition, I'd recommend using `mdfind -name libboost_mpi` rather than `locate`, primarily because spotlight indexes pretty much immediately while locate relies on the scheduled update period

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! Although I did find this illuminating, `brew install boost --with-mpi --without-single --layout=system` did not solve my problem (I updated my question to reflect this).

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear - you have to *edit* the boost formula and change the line that mentions `--layout=tagged`. It doesn't actually make use of the option when passed in to the `brew install` command. If you don't want to rebuild boost, you should link using `-lboost_mpi-mt`