# Homebrew - Boost failed to build on 10.10.5 Yosemite with layout=system and --build-from-source

Tags: c++, boost, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am attempting to build the Boost library from Homebrew. I am using layout=system to get an untagged build (based on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30713508/4718738)), but the build does not go through. The error message is as follows:

```
error: Name clash for '<p/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib>libboost_system.dylib'
error: 
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having 
error: these incompatible properties:
error: 
error:     -  <threading>multi
error:     -  <threading>single
error: 
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these 
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

Here is a link to the [homebrew generated gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/722ff803879a9ccd3902). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue on the Homebrew repository and was quickly assisted. I needed to use the option --without-single.

```
brew reinstall boost --build-from-source --without-single
```